# QLineGradient ровные границы между цветами

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Задача состоит в том, чтобы во всех `item's`, которые находятся в первой колонке `QTreeWidget` закрасить `background`, но не просто одним цветом, а должно быть закрашено 40% ширины `item'a` одним цветом, другие 60% другим и еще не большое условие, границы между цветами, должны быть ровными, без размытия, эффекта смешивания цветов. Пробую так:

```
self.treeWidget = QTreeWidget()
self.treeWidget.setColumnCount(3)
self.treeWidget.setHeaderLabels(['1', '2', '3'])
self.treeWidget.addTopLevelItem(QTreeWidgetItem(['item1', 'item2', 'item3']))
grad = QLinearGradient(QPointF(0, 0),QPointF(self.treeWidget.columnWidth(0), 0))                                            
grad.setStops([(0.4, QColor(255, 0, 0)),(0.41, QColor(0, 255, 0)),])
grad.setCoordinateMode(QLinearGradient.CoordinateMode.ObjectBoundingMode)
self.treeWidget.topLevelItem(0).setBackground(0, grad)
```

Собственно получается ерунда, как сделать правильно? Может лучше использовать другой способ? Какой?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Дело было в координатном пространстве, от которого рассчитывается ширина градиента, просто нужно было перевести в логический мод:

```
grad = QLinearGradient(QPointF(0, 0), QPointF(self.treeWidget.columnWidth(2), 0))
stop1 = round(itemListSell[i]['total'] / maxSellOrder, 2)
stop2 = stop1 + 0.01
grad.setStops([(stop1, QColor(255, 0, 0)),(stop2, QColor(0, 255, 0)),])                               grad.setCoordinateMode(QLinearGradient.CoordinateMode.LogicalMode)
```

И теперь `QLinearGradient.CoordinateMode.LogicalMode`, берет координаты с ширины столбца, в реальных размерах, а не (x1: 0, x2: 0 y1: 1, y2: 1)
И да, чтобы границы градиента были четкие и ровные, без размытия - нужно использовать минимальные границы между переходов цветов, у меня они прописаны в переменных `stop1` и `stop2`

Answer (score 1):

градиент как бы градиент и задаст :) Тут надо немного сложнее. Отрисовывать фон самостоятельно, перегружая `QTreeWidget::drawRow`

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush, QColor
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, QRect

# Нам нужен свой "кастомный" виджет, в котором перегрузим отрисовку строки 
class MyTreeWidget(QTreeWidget):
    def drawRow(self, painter, option, index):   # Перегружаем отрисовку строки
        if index.column() == 0:   # фон меняем только для первого столбца
            rect = self.visualRect(index)   # узнаем геометрическое расположение ячейки
            corner = rect.width() * 0.6   # вычисляем ширину по которой будут разделяться цвета
            rect1 = QRect(rect.left(), rect.top(), corner, rect.height())   # прямоугольник для первого цвета
            rect2 = QRect(rect.left() + corner, rect.top(), rect.width() - corner, rect.height())   # то же самое для второго
            # отрисовываем фон
            painter.save()
            brush = QBrush(QColor(255, 0, 0))
            painter.fillRect(rect1, brush)
            brush = QBrush(QColor(0, 255, 0))
            painter.fillRect(rect2, brush)
            painter.restore()
        super(QTreeWidget, self).drawRow(painter, option, index)   # дальнейшей отрисовкой занимается оригинальный QTreeWidget::drawRow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(400, 400))
        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        grid_layout = QGridLayout()
        self.treeWidget = MyTreeWidget()
        self.treeWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.treeWidget.setHeaderLabels(['1', '2', '3'])
        self.treeWidget.addTopLevelItem(QTreeWidgetItem(['myitem11', 'item12', 'item13']))
        self.treeWidget.addTopLevelItem(QTreeWidgetItem(['item21', 'item22', 'item23']))
        central_widget.setLayout(grid_layout)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.treeWidget, 0, 0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Сразу стоит отметить что можно конечно фон отрисовать используя обычный `QTrwwWidgetItem::setBackground(column, brush)`, но такой фон не будет никак реагировать на изменение размера ячеек

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ, но я уже решил эту проблему), все было легко и просто, мое решение ниже